# Simple Python + Gtk.Window

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, image, gtk

I'm learning Python and Gtk so I decided to write a simple application that will take some image let user annotate with a pen and send results through email or save to a file.

So far I have the skeleton of the interface:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
import os, sys  

class GUI:

image = 0;

def __init__(self):

    self.window = Gtk.Window()
    self.window.set_title ("Imagine")
    self.window.connect_after('destroy', self.destroy)
    self.window.set_border_width(10)
    self.window.set_default_size(400, 200)

    self.window.vbox = Gtk.Box()
    self.window.vbox.set_spacing (5)
    self.window.vbox.set_orientation (Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
    self.window.add (self.window.vbox)


    self.window.hbox = Gtk.ButtonBox()
    self.window.vbox.add(self.window.hbox)

    self.window.new_button = Gtk.Button(label="New")
    self.window.new_button.connect("clicked", self.on_new_clicked)
    self.window.hbox.pack_start(self.window.new_button, False, False, 0)

    self.window.save_button = Gtk.Button(label="Save")
    self.window.save_button.connect("clicked", self.on_save_clicked)
    self.window.hbox.pack_start(self.window.save_button, False, False, 0)

    self.window.email_button = Gtk.Button(label="eMail")
    self.window.email_button.connect("clicked", self.on_email_clicked)
    self.window.hbox.pack_start(self.window.email_button, False, False, 0)

    self.window.pen_button = Gtk.Button(label="Pen")
    self.window.pen_button.connect("clicked", self.on_pen_clicked)
    self.window.hbox.pack_start(self.window.pen_button, False, False, 0)

    self.image = Gtk.Image()
    self.window.vbox.pack_start (self.image, False, False, 0)

    self.window.show_all()

def on_save_clicked(self, widget):
    print("fixme: Save Clicked") 

def on_email_clicked(self, widget):
    print("fixme: eMail Clicked") 

def on_pen_clicked(self, widget):
    print("fixme: Pen Clicked") 

def on_new_clicked (self, button):
    print("fixme: New Clicked")#code below is just to test the image panel works
    dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog ("Open Image", button.get_toplevel(), Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN);
    dialog.add_button ("Cancel", 0)
    dialog.add_button ("Ok", 1)
    dialog.set_default_response(1)

    filefilter = Gtk.FileFilter ()
    filefilter.add_pixbuf_formats ()
    dialog.set_filter(filefilter)

    if dialog.run() == 1:
        self.image.set_from_file(dialog.get_filename())

    dialog.destroy()

def destroy(self, window):
    Gtk.main_quit()

class Controls:

    def send_email (self):
        print("fixme: Send Email")

    def pen_controls (self):
        print("fixme: Pen Controls") 


    def on_save_clicked(self, widget):
        print("fixme: Save Clicked") 


def main () :
    win = GUI()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Can you please review my code and let me know what could have been done better? Any documentation along will be highly appreciated.

Also, my main doubts are:

- Is my code compliant with the object oriented Python?
- Will `vbox` and `hbox` exist in two places in my window because I created them in `self.window` and then added to the window again with `self.window.add`?
- Should I have created `vbox` and `hbox` outside of `window` and then used the `window.add` command?
- The idea is to use Gtk3 PyGObject and Python 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think your considerations are a big problem.

However what I think is a bigger problem is the amount of verbosity and repetition in your code. While the code is readable as is, adding more elements in the future will make your `__init__()` method inflate and become unreadable.

This is because you are adding each Element individually. In large applications this is largely unfeasible when you have more than a dozen widgets, for reasons I am sure you can understand.

There are a couple of solutions to this:

### Generate Layout using code

instead of doing this:

```
self.window.new_button = Gtk.Button(label="New")
self.window.new_button.connect("clicked", self.on_new_clicked)
self.window.hbox.pack_start(self.window.new_button, False, False, 0)

# ... repeat for all buttons
```

you can do this

```
buttons = [("New", self.on_new_clicked),
           ("Save", self.on_save_clicked),
           ("eMail", self.on_email_clicked),
           ("Pen", self.on_pen_clicked),
          ]

for name, callback in buttons:
    b = Gtk.Button(label=button)
    b.connect("clicked", callback)
    self.window.hbox.pack_start(b, False, False, 0)
```

### Subclass standard widgets

Often you can also clean up your application by subclassing other widgets:

```
class myButtonBox(Gtk.ButtonBox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # add all buttons to self here

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # note: super() without args works only in new versions of Python
```

### Seperate Interface and logic by using `GtkBuilder` xml

I am mentioning this last since this is the best option, but not very frequently worth the effort.

The Gtk 3 Tutorial has a [very nice page on GtkBuilder](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/builder.html)

> The Gtk.Builder class offers you the opportunity to design user
>   interfaces without writing a single line of code. This is possible
>   through describing the interface by a XML file and then loading the
>   XML description at runtime and create the objects automatically, which
>   the Builder class does for you. For the purpose of not needing to
>   write the XML manually the Glade application lets you create the user
>   interface in a WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) manner
>
> This method has several advantages:
>
> - Less code needs to be written.
> - UI changes can be seen more quickly, so UIs are able to improve.
> - Designers without programming skills can create and edit UIs.
> - The description of the user interface is independent from the programming language being used.
>
> There is still code required for handling interface changes triggered by the user,
>   but Gtk.Builder allows you to focus on implementing that
>   functionality.

Comment: Good review thanks! Just a question: I'm not sure I understand the second point `Subclass standard widgets`. Would this work essentially as the `extends` in inheritance ? So if I did that for every button they would all be a subclass implementation of ButtonBox instead of a new Button Object?

Comment: It is just a way of separating your Code into more parts, your `extends` analogy is pretty fitting. In this case `myButtonBox` would be a `ButtonBox` with your Buttons included automatically. I have updated my post to be more clear